# Can not retrieve component template while routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vuejs. This is main js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;


new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is router:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ControlExcel from './components/ControlExcel';
import Login from "./components/Login";
import blog from './components/blog';
import file from './components/file';


Vue.use(VueRouter);

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/control-excel',
        name: 'ControlExcel',
        component: ControlExcel
    }
    ,
    {
        path: '/loginn',
        component: Login
    }
    ,
    {
        path: '/blog',
        name: 'blog',
        component: blog
    }
    ,
    {
        path: '/file',
        name: 'file',
        component: file
    },


];

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: "",
    routes
})
```

and this app vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
<!--    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">-->
<!--    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>-->

<!--    <ControlExcel />-->

<!--      <component v-bind:is="component" />-->
<span>abcd</span>




      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/control-excel">exce</router-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/loginn">loginn</router-link>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/blog">blog</router-link>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/file">file</router-link>
      </li>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
// import Login from './components/Login.vue'
// import ControlExcel from "./components/ControlExcel";
// import Login from "./components/Login";
import file from './components/file';
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('file',file);

// import DownloadExcel from './components/DownloadExcel'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
      // Login,
      // ControlExcel,

  }
  ,
    data() {
        return {
            // component: "Login"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

At localhost:8080, i see those:

```
abcd
exce
loginn
blog
file
```

When i click any of them,  URl changes. for example 
http://localhost:8080/file
for **file** but it does not bring component.

for example for  **file**:

```
  {
        path: '/file',
        name: 'file',
        component: file
    },
```

that component **file.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="blog">
        <h1>fasfsasd</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        name:'file'
        }

</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

This is directory:

```
src 
-components
--blog.vue
--ControlExcel.vue
--file.vue
--Login.vue
router.js
main.js
App.vue
```

Why cant it bring template also?

There is dynamic component but i dont want to use it and it does not seem best practice, like this:

```
<component v-bind:is=”currentComponent”></component>
```

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-your-components-dynamic-in-vue-js/

Answer (score 2):

Your Vue-Router does not change the main component, but only puts the component of the URL that matches into `<router-view></router-view>`, which you don't have.
You need to add it to your main component.

For example like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <span>abcd</span>
  <ul>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/control-excel">exce</router-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/loginn">loginn</router-link>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/blog">blog</router-link>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/file">file</router-link>
      </li>
  </ul>

  <router-view></router-view>

</div>
```

Comment: I put all div in **app.vue** inside ``router-view`` so, it will change when it will clicked. That is best practice?